# How do you add an item to an Array in MQL4?

Tags: arrays, mql4

I'm trying to create an Array in MQL4, and on every tick I want to add a new value to array[0] and push the rest of the items back, so the old array[0] becomes array[1] and array[1] becomes array[2] and so on.  I want to be able to do this an unlimited number of times, once per tick.  Then I can access the value from the previous tick using array[1], but I can also access its current value array[0].  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have an array of primitives in MQL4, the problem here is that you will have to copy them all each tick which is waste of time and resources. If you want to save some more advanced data (let's say `MqlTick`), you have to store it as the structure or create a class and save classes. It should be really senseless to copy all objects, that is why you should think of applying `CList` or `CArrayObj` and adding objects to the end. Simple magic would help to call element with index 0:

```
#include <Arrays\ArrayObj.mqh>
class CTick : public CObject{
   public: double m_bid, m_ask;
   CTick(const double bid,const double ask):m_bid(bid),m_ask(ask){}
};
CArrayObj *listOfTicks;
CTick *getTickByShift(const int shift=0)
   {
    return listOfTicks.At(listOfTicks.Total()-1-shift));
   }
int OnInit(){
    listOfTicks=new CArrayObj();
    return(1);
}
void OnTick(){
   listOfTicks.Add(new CTick(Bid,Ask));
   //example of accessing ticks 0 and 3, keep in mind you do not have 3 at start!
   double bid0=getTickByShift(0).m_bid;
   double ask3=getTickByShift(3).m_ask;
}
void OnDeinit(const int reason){delete listOfTicks;}
```

If you need really unlimited number of operations - probably 2^31-1 would be enough for you, to speed up you may think of `listOfTicks.Step(1000);` to have 1000 empty slots and do not resize(=copy all to the new location) the array every tick.

Comment: I don't really need "infinite", just one for every bar, so for long back-tests it will require a lot.  It's actually running on every bar, not on every tick, but I already have the code for that so I didn't include it in the info.  Your answer looks very promising and I shall try it :)

Comment: What i'm really trying to do is add the equivalent of how high and low work.  For high you can go high[5] or high[400] to grab previous candle highs, and i'm trying to basically make my own variables that do that.  I have one that changes constantly based on different conditions, and I need to be able to go var[5] or var[50] at any given time.  So like a series in tradingview (converting my tradingview script to mql4)

Comment: add `void OnDeInit(const int reason){delete(listOfTicks);}` in order to kill remaining objects at end

Comment: `CArrayObj` wraps an array of `CObject*`. In most cases it is the most efficient collection, however, insertion in incredibly inefficient due to shifting the entire array each time something is inserted. In this case it would be much better to use `CList` instead.

Comment: `CList` would be nice if need to add or remove to start/end/random place, but it is not quite convenient to get `i-th` element. Arrays work faster then linked lists in all the languages that is why I suggested `CArrayObj` and inverted access to the element by index

Comment: Ahh... I didn't see that you inverted the index. Clever. Nice work.

Answer (score 0):

I did this native work-around solution (No libraries needed) where you just need to declare the array globally, and then call the function whenever you want to push a new value.

```
double Array[] = {};
int MaxArraySize = 100;

void PushElement(double value){

   double tempArray[];
   int count = ArraySize(Array); if(count > MaxArraySize){count = MaxArraySize;}
   ArrayCopy(tempArray, Array, 1, 0, count);    
   tempArray[0] = value;        
   ArrayCopy(Array, tempArray, 0, 0, WHOLE_ARRAY);      

}
```

Make sure to set the variable MaxArraySize to the desired array limit.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to modify more than one specific array. In that case you can use a reference to the array you want to modify. No additional libraries or binding to one global array.

```
void PushElement(int &inputArray[], int value)
{
   int tempArray[];
   int count = ArraySize(inputArray);
   ArrayCopy(tempArray, inputArray, 1, 0, count);
   tempArray[0] = value;
   ArrayCopy(inputArray, tempArray, 0, 0);
}
```